# Multivariable Limits Involving Sines and Logs

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've been stuck on this for a while now and was wondering if anyone could help me out by starting off in the right direction. Thanks.

Find $$\lim_{x,y \to 0} \frac{\sin xy}{\ln(x^2+y^2+1)}$$

Comment: Can you solve $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}?$$

Answer (score 1):

Change $(x,\, y)$ to polar coordinates:
$$\begin{cases}
x=\rho\cos{\theta},\\
y=\rho\sin{\theta}.
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\lim\limits_{(x,\,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin {xy}}{\ln{(x^2+y^2+1)}}=
\lim\limits_{\rho \to 0} \dfrac{\sin {(\rho^2 \sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}) }}{\ln{(1 + \rho^2)}}=\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$$
which depends on $\theta,$ therefore, limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try $x=0$ and $y=x$ as paths to approach $(0,0)$.

Comment: After I make a substitution, can I then use l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: I guess that basic limits will suffice...